# How to modify Negative Axis Bar Graph in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a negative Axis Bar Graph using Highcharts but the format in which I would like it to be is not appearing. I am not able to manipulate it to the format as shown.

My output for the code mentioned below is attached. http://jsfiddle.net/00bh7yp7/2/

```
// Age categories 
var categories = [
        '0-4', '5-9', '10-14', '15-19',
        '20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44',
        '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69',
        '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85-89', '90-94',
        '95-99', '100 + ' ];

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Population pyramid for Germany, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://populationpyramid.net/germany/2015/">Population Pyramids of the World from 1950 to 2100</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories,
            reversed: false,
            offset: 0,
            labels: {
                step: 1
            },

        },
        yAxis: {

            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Math.abs(this.value) + '%';
                }
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
               stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                    'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Male',
            data: [-2.2, -2.2, -2.3, -2.5, -2.7, -3.1, -3.2,
                -3.0, -3.2, -4.3, -4.4, -3.6, -3.1, -2.4,
                -2.5, -2.3, -1.2, -0.6, -0.2, -0.0, -0.0]
        }, {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [2.1, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.1, 2.9,
                3.1, 4.1, 4.3, 3.6, 3.4, 2.6, 2.9, 2.9,
                1.8, 1.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.0]
        }] });
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**
[image]

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**
[image]

I just am looking for formatting so that the Category Scale comes in between the two graphs and then we can manage it further. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of achieving that spacing is using **two y axes** and positioning them with `left` and `width` properties (they're not documented in the API, but they work):

```
  yAxis: [{
    left: '55%',
    width: '45%'
    (...)
  }, {
    reversed: true,
    width: '45%',
    offset: 0
    (...)
  }],
  series: [{
    data: [1, 3]
  }, {
    data: [2, 5],
    yAxis: 1
  }]
```

X axis is treated similarly:

```
  xAxis: {
    left: '50%',
    (...)
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/dx2vj8k1/

Comment: Loved it. Really witty Solution :)

Comment: The problem occurred again. This graph is not responsive. When I make it a widget I would not like the percentage values as window.innerHeight

Comment: Could you provide some live demo of your problem? The graph I prepared is responsive, but it's a simplified version - it uses percentages. Better approach would be to compute pixels (in `chart.events.redner`) and use them instead. This would give you a possibility to create values that will prevent overlapping of some elements (e.g. data labels when the chart width is very small).